# Difference in the meaning between "consistent in applying the rules" and "consistent to apply the rules"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "We must be consistent in applying the rules" and "We must be consistent to apply the rules" ?

Answer (score 1):

> We must be consistent in applying the rules

is unambiguous, it is talking about how we apply the rules. The word **in** indicates that we are thinking about how we **apply** the rules, we should do so consistently

> We must be consistent to apply the rules

Is not quite idiomatic, I don't think a native speaker would say this. The word **to** can mean **to be able to** so it seems to imply that we, the individual, need to have the quality of consistency in order that we shall be able to apply the rules.